# Apply function to multiple columns, when column headers are in list

Tags: python, pandas

I have a function below, which is designed to work on one column

I have a list of column headers, in dataframe df.

```
cols=[col1,col2,col3]
def retention(adstock_rate, df,variablename):
    adstocked_advertising = []
    for i, row in enumerate(df.iterrows()):
        if i == 0: 
            adstocked_advertising.append(df[variablename][i])
        else:
            adstocked_advertising.append(df[variablename][i] + adstock_rate * adstocked_advertising[i-1]) 
    outname=variablename+"_RET"+str(int(adstock_rate*100))
    se = pd.Series(adstocked_advertising)
    df[outname] = se.values
```

Out of curiosity, is it possible to use a lambda or something to apply this function to multiple columns? (I am currently using a for loop)

Comment: Can you add some sample data and expected output?

Comment: I guess, for your use case, there is nothing better than a for loop..
Out of curiosity, what is the problem with for loop approach??

Comment: no problem with loop, just trying to understand python a little more, instead of reverting back to my vba approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well first of all, you don't seem to be using the `cols` variable so I'm not sure what you're applying by column. Nevertheless, the `DataFrame.apply` method should do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps like this?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':np.arange(5,10,1)})

def retention( df,variablename,adstock_rate ):
    result=[df[variablename][0]]+[adstock_rate * last_a + this_a for this_a, last_a in zip(df[variablename][1:], df[variablename])]
    outname=variablename+"_RET"+str(int(adstock_rate*100))
    df[outname]=result
    return result

retention(df,'A',0.5)
```

Result:

```
   A  A_RET50
0  5      5.0
1  6      8.5
2  7     10.0
3  8     11.5
4  9     13.0
```